# What folders need to be mounted before chroot?

Tags: boot, chroot

I am attempting to update a broken Linux Mint 32 bit installation using chroot from a live cd. Different websites give different folders that need to be mounted before `chroot`.

The error I am trying to solve is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567730/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-ubuntu-vg-root-doesnt-exist/567897#567897)
What folders to mount and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well; gentoo wiki is very nice in that respect; *(assuming that you are booted to working environment like livecd/usb)*
first we assume your chroot system is on /dev/sdaX. so we go mount it:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/distro
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/distro
```

if your chroot (problematic environment) has seprate `/boot`, `/var` or any other partitions we mount them like above.

```
root #mount -o bind /proc /mnt/distro/proc
```

then depend on what kind of system you are building (systemd or init ):

```
root #mount --rbind /sys /mnt/distro/sys 
root #mount --make-rslave /mnt/distro/sys 
root #mount --rbind /dev /mnt/distro/dev 
root #mount --make-rslave /mnt/distro/dev
```

if youare building init-based system like `OpenRc` don't do `--make-rslave` lines.

then to chroot in a right way do this:

```
root #chroot /mnt/distro /bin/env -i TERM=$TERM /bin/bash 
root #source /etc/profile 
root #export PS1="(chroot) $PS1"
```

*Note; that your chroot environment may differ and `/bin/env` wasn't
there. so it should be at `usr/bin/env`.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am using systemd, what will change must be made if I am using init?

Comment: first; it is regarding your chroot os. and if the os you want to chroot in uses systemd do the `--make-rslave` lines if not don't.